# How to get XML stored in a javascript object into a dojo store

Tags: seam, dojo

I am currently using Seam remoting, which returns a list of data from my backing bean and would like to import the resulting XML formatted data into a dojo store.  This could then be displayed in a datagrid.

Unfortunately the dojox.data.XmlStore only has the facility to accept a URL and not an object.

Is there some other way of getting an XML document stored in a javascript object into a dojo store?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend xmlstores functionality yourself, try the following link for example

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/data/XmlStore-examples.html#dojox-data-xmlstore-examples